# Comando Artisan para não perder os dados da base de dados

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Olá estou começando a trabalhar com o laravel 5 e estou tendo um problema quando executo os comandos migrate os dados são perdidos no banco de dados, isso é esperado?

o comando `php artisan migrate` funciona na primeira chamada e os outros `php artisan refresh` e `php artisan reset` faz com que os dados da base sejam perdidos, há algum comando especifico para isso?

Answer (score 1):

Se você fizer alterações como adicionar/deletar uma coluna de alguma tabela é recomendado criar uma nova migration parecida com essa

```
<?php 

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddColumnOwnerToLikes extends Migration
{
    /**
      * Run the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
    */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('likes' , function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('user_id');
    });

}

    /**
      * Reverse the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
     //
    }

}
```

depois de criar a migration rode o comando:

```
php artisan migrate
```

logo após a execução a sua nova coluna será criada ou deletada.

Com os comandos:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan migrate:reset
```

os dados serão apagados, pois todas as tabelas serão deletadas e recriadas

Comment: entendi... o estranho é que no decorrer de uma aplicação essas alterações e migrations podem ficar incontroláveis ou seja, muitas migrations para uma tabela, que ainda por cima se terá dados. entende

Comment: Você terá total controle sobre suas migrations, apenas crie quando precisar alterar a estrutura das tabelas e tudo ficará como antes, apenas tome cuidado para não fazer edições drásticas que podem impedir o funcionamento da aplicação